# How can I pass parameter to stored procedure through a query?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(OUT `vote_value` INT, OUT `score` INT, IN `user_id` INT, IN `time_range` INT)
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    SELECT coalesce(sum(vote_value), 0), coalesce(sum(score), 0)
      INTO vote_value, score
    FROM reputations
    WHERE owner_id = user_id
      AND date_time > CASE time_range
          WHEN 'WEEK' 
          THEN  unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
          WHEN 'MONTH' 
          THEN  unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
          WHEN 'YEAR' 
          THEN  unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
          ELSE 1 END;
END
```

As you see my procedure gets 4 parameters. Both `vote_value` and `score` have `OUT` direction *(as result)*, And both `user_id` and `time_range` have `IN` Direction. So I have to pass those two which have `IN` direction when I call the procedure.

Ok, I can call procedure about like this:

```
CALL test(@vote_value, @score, 10, 'WEEK');
SELECT @vote_value, @score;
```

It would work as well. But please focus on the third parameter which is `10`. I don't want to pass it manually by hand. I want it be a value from a query. Something like this:

```
CALL test(@vote_value, @score, u.id, 'WEEK');
SELECT id, @vote_value, @score FROM Users u;
```

But it throws *syntax error*. Does anybody know how can I do such a thing? The expected result is [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/76d67a1e76d37fc2e2daf737e6eb80fc).

Comment: Why not rewrite your `Procecure` to `Function`. `Function` can be called within `Select` statement

Comment: @Charlesliam Because functions return only one value as result in mysql.

Comment: not totally good suggestion. Separate the procedure to 2 Functions will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id into @id FROM Users LIMIT 1;
CALL test(@vote_value, @score, @id, 'WEEK');
```

Try above code.

As mention in above code you can get value of that **`id`** using **`SELECT id into @id`**  and then use that **`@id`** as parameter for that query.